# setButtonDrawable to a customized radioButton in ListView can't show the correct result until click it

Tags: android, listview

I use an example to make this issue easy to understand.
I have a ListView.  In each row, there's an customized RadioButton which is extended from RadioButton.  I use setButtonDrawable to set the image of this button in getView();  I use ViewHolder method to hold the button.

```
holder.button.setButtonDrawable(drawable);
```

The ListView has 4 rows.  In each screen, we can only see one row.  Now the problem is: when I scroll the ListView, I found buttons in the first and the third item are the same, second and fourth are the same.  But I'm sure I have set different images to them.

What's the problem?  Does the button should be refresh after setButtonDrawable?

Thank you.

Comment: are you setting and getting Tags for the rows?

Comment: Since it's in listview, you need to call 'notifydatasetchanged()' to refresh the listview

Comment: hi @Anuj Yes, I set the holder as tag.

Comment: Hi @mango Can I call notifyDatasetChanged() in getView?  I think this may cause infinite loop.

Comment: You're right. You can't just put it in there or you might get stutters. I was thinking you'd do it in some on click listener or after some event that changes your drawables. But it doesn't need to be there. Can be outside the adapter too